# Breakpoint with componentsSeparatedByString()

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, breakpoints

I am using `MapKit` for an app.

I am storing information in a **global dictionary** and am accessing them again.

Each is stored with a key of **text + username + date**. The username variable in this instance contains the date and the username for the string

```
func mapView (mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView{
    var pinView = MKPinAnnotationView()
    var imageView: UIImageView = UIImageView()
    var button: UIButton = UIButton()
    let username = annotation.title!.componentsSeparatedByString(" - ")
    var string: String = annotation.subtitle! + username[0] + username[1] as String!
    println(string)
    println(PPs[string])
    var pp = PPs[string]
```

On the `username = annotation.title`  line it stops at a breakpoint (I have turned them off) with this line.

```
 EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_ARM_BREAKPOINT, subcode=0xe7ffdefe)
```

I am wondering what is wrong when i declare username, I have tried both let and var.

Answer (score 1):

That most likely means that either `annotation` or `annotation.title` is nil. I suggest to put a breakpoint at the first line of the function body and inspect the `annotation` parameter.

Comment: Thank you but it was a bug in xcode, the error was on the wrong line